# .resx file same key with different case

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, localization

I am trying to localize my app and according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization.  I am using English phrases as my keys and French translation as my value.  Unfortunately, I have quite a few keys that are the same but that differ in case (i.e., "Hello World" and "HELLO WORLD").

The .resx designer will not allow you to enter the two keys, but if I edit it in text mode, my app builds, and the resources get embedded.  However, one, of the "Hello World"'s is missing.

Is there a way to do this, and if not, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

It's mentioned in that "About Title" example of the tutorial that:

> Alternatively, you can use the traditional approach and provide a key
>   to retrieve the default language string.

So an option is to use resource keys instead of the actual strings (see section on [Working with resource files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization#working-with-resource-files)). Then when you add the string keys to the resources, as noted in this [Naming Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-resources) guidelines, use [Pascal Casing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) instead for your resource keys.

This means:

- No spaces
- No keys that differ only in case

Taking your example of "Hello World" and "HELLO WORLD", you can differentiate them by adding a prefix/suffix identifier, like this:

`HelloWorldDnCase`
`HelloWorldUpCase`

But, if you still want to use the actual strings as the key (similar to the "About Title") example, you could just use a single key, "Hello World", then just programmatically upcase the wording when you need it to be displayed in all-uppercase.

Comment: Disregard top comment.  I was under the impression that the .NET Core way is to use the English phrase as the key, so you can use the StringLocalizer like this:  _localizer["Hello World!"].  The default implementation of StringLocalizer will use the ResourceManager behind the scenes so the string must be in the resx file as "Hello World!" with space and everything.  Am I misunderstanding the tutorial:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization.

Comment: @GrantParker As described in that "About Title" example, what `StringLocalizer` does is: _"If the localized value of "About Title" is not found, then the indexer key is returned, that is, the string "About Title"_. This makes it simpler early on into the development. It also says that _"Alternatively, you can use the traditional approach and provide a key to retrieve the default language string"_, which is what you can do to implement your strings that differ only in case. See the section on **Working with resource files**.

Comment: This is stupid implementation from Microsoft. This means that a phrase with different casing won't be translated, and I have no other means of fixing this in the localization than to change the actual phrase that goes into the localizer. It's like they deliberately want to make the code uglier. At least provide an option to disable case insensitivity in the .resx file!